# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'

Tags: react-native, gradlew

I want to ask something, I have an app, on the other day, my app is working perfectly, and somehow today, my app won't work on Android (when I start it), but when I run on IOS, it is working, the log said like:

```
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
[:react-native-google-signin_google-signin] /Users/mydocs/node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin/android/build/intermediates/merged_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
        Package name 'com.reactnativegooglesignin' used in: :react-native-google-signin_google-signin, :react-native-google-signin-google-signin.
/Users/mydocs/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
/Users/mydocs/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

and this is my manifest in  section:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="login"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I've tried to search for gradlew error, but still haven't figured it out yet

Comment: Same happened to me, still can't figure out what's going on.....

Comment: Yea, we are the same, and until now, i'm still trying to figure it out, if you @Gayane know how to fixed this, please let me know

Comment: Sure, will let you know

Comment: Hey @Gayane, i thnk you should check the answer below

Comment: Thank you for pinging @haksatrya-bhaswara, the solution worked for us as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For us changing:

> implementation
> 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'

with

> 'implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:14.1.1'

on build.gradle seems to work

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/1114

Maybe it can fix for u too